# How can I mount / inspect a docker's container entire root filesystem on the host?

Tags: docker

Is there a way I can mount the entire 'filesystem' of the container on the host? Does this filesystem perhaps already exist somewhere on the host?

My use case would be so I can more easily search files as well as modify files on the container (useful for debugging / development etc).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding these files are stored via the storage driver. And it seems for the default 'overlay' these are stored as regular files.

I've managed to find the files at this directory:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir}}' containerIdGoesHere
```

Another possible solution is: https://github.com/wagoodman/dive